# Floating point numbers take only two digit after number

Tags: php

Doing an billing application in php, There come price with decimals like 0.576 tried

round()
number_format()

it will give me 0.58 but i want 0.57 only, how can i get in php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
floor(0.576*100)/100
//0.57
```

Using `round` with `PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN` wont work as it only affect the way decimal 5 is rounded. It does not truncate the float value.

```
round(0.576, 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
//0.58 //Not good

round(0.575, 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
//0.57 //Good but will not work above this value (e.g 0.0576, 0.0577...)
```

Answer (score -1):

A fraction higher than `.5` is always rounded up. If you already have found `round` why haven't you looked at the documentation:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Try:

```
echo round( 0.676, 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN );
```

Comment: it seems like your code give 0.68 and the point of the question would be to give 0.67 with your example.

Comment: @feela , PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN only for half (0.5).